CMake Include and Lib directories
CMakeList.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)
project(raylibPhysicsEngine)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(PROJECT_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/main.c)

This is the extent of my CMake knowledge.
And this is my current CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(raylibPhysicsEngine)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(FetchContent)
set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)
set(BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(BUILD_GAMES    OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

FetchContent_Declare(
        raylib
        GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/raysan5/raylib.git"
        GIT_TAG "master"
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(raylib)

file(GLOB_RECURSE PROJECT_SOURCES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/*.cpp")
set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/main.c"
        "src/ds.c"
)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
        src/macros.h)
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PROJECT_INCLUDE})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE raylib ${PROJECT_LIB})

target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ASSETS_PATH="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/")

I had copied this from a video tutorial, I dont remeber what know but problem is that I want to be able to use cmake to get files from a include dir and a lib dir.
Maybe its just me but all CMake learning resource ive tried have not helped me.
I have tried everything i can but i just dont understand what half of this stuff means and what it does and the documentation is very helpful. I know make and i use it for most of my c related projects.
All i need is for cmake to get raylib from the lib directory and any other headers and libraries that i decide to but in include and lib. More importantly can you explain what the functions are doing instead of saying type this.
My current fs is:


├───include
│       macros.h
│       stb_ds.h
│       typedef.h
│
├───lib
│       ds.c
│
└───src
        main.c

 CMakeLists.txt




Your CMake code seems to download raylib and link your project with that library. Does it work? If not, then what error do you get? What exact approaches you have tried to solve the error? Asking to explain you a code which you have taken from somewhere is not so useful, especially when you don't tell what is exactly unclear for you.

Sorry if I was unclear but it does work. Want I want to know is how can I make it so I can copy raylib into a lib directory then link the lib in c make Same with include directories

Linking with a library is performed with target_link_libraries command. If you have a library which is already built, then for linking with it see that question. Specifying include directories is performed with target_include_directories command.

None of that questin makes sense to me what are the params what directories waht am i puttin in add_lib??

You probably need to spend some time for learning CMake. E.g. by their tutorial.

OK, i can not show you all of CMake in an answer but i can quickly walk you through this example of yours and then i recommend you to look at the excellent tutorial Modern CMake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(raylibPhysicsEngine)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

These are obvious. Please have in mind that some cmake commands need to be before or after the project command or they do not work (sometimes without an error, very annoying). This is the case for eg for compiler related variables.
Another command that i usually include in this part of my CMakeLists is set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
include(FetchContent)
set(FETCHCONTENT_QUIET FALSE)
set(BUILD_EXAMPLES OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
set(BUILD_GAMES    OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)

FetchContent_Declare(
        raylib
        GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/raysan5/raylib.git"
        GIT_TAG "master"
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(raylib)

This tells cmake to download the master branch from this git repository and include it in the build. As raylib happens to also be a cmake project, its provides targets that can be used to build your own code.
file(GLOB_RECURSE PROJECT_SOURCES CONFIGURE_DEPENDS
     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/*.cpp")

this searches recursively the specified path/regexp for cpp files and saves them in a list named PROJECT_SOURCES
set(PROJECT_SOURCES
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/main.c"
    "src/ds.c"
)

Now this one overwrites PROJECT_SOURCES with these 2 c files. I would expect to have used list(APPEND PROJECT_SOURCES ... ) instead
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
               src/macros.h)
target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCES})

Here comes the essence of CMake. We ask it to create an executable named PROJECT_NAME. The macros.h is not a compiled file but it is good to include it in the list of a target build files so that CMake can track their modification and recompile as needed. The target_sources command is arguably too verbose, it would suffice to have the ${PROJECT_SOURCES} after the macros.h
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${PROJECT_INCLUDE})

search for include files in ${PROJECT_INCLUDE}
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE raylib ${PROJECT_LIB})

link the executable with raylib (which was made available from the FetchContent command earlier) and ${PROJECT_LIB} (not specified in the file you show us). Have in mind that if ${PROJECT_LIB} doesn't exist, CMake will not complain(i think) and that is one reason to use targets (eg raylib) instead of variable names
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
                           ASSETS_PATH="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/")

finally, it specifies -DASSETS_PATH="${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/assets/" . the ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} is replaced with the actual path at cmake configure time.
Good luck and have fun.
